# Robot framework identify card types using if condition

Tags: python, string, selenium, collections, robotframework

Before selecting button, need to check either input or output card.
need a logic to identify either it is INPUT or OUTPUT Card using robot framework and if condition  for web automation testing.

```
 **IO CARDS**
  SLOT 1 :DI
  SLOT 2 :DI
  SLOT 3 :DI
  SLOT 4 :DI
  SLOT 5 :DO
  SLOT 6 :DO
  SLOT 7 :DI
```

Please try to solve this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here 7 buttons is there,  and different logic for both DI & DO buttons.  so, need to cross verify either it is input or output card   using if condition .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
${elementId}= |  Set Variable | Slot${slotNumber}BTN
Log To Console |  ${elementId}    

Click Element   |    slot${slotNumber}BTN
Sleep |  3s
 
${slotLink} =  |  get text   | id=slot${slotNumber}BTN        
Log to Console |  ${slotLink}  
IF   | '${slotLink}'== 'Slot ${slotNumber} : DI'        
    Validate Input Card Options  ${slotNumber}
END
IF   | '${slotLink}'== 'Slot ${slotNumber} : DO'        
    Validate Output Card Options  ${slotNumber}
END
```